# Override the 'from address' in Apex mail in SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

Hi I am setting the from address in apex using the below method.

```
mail.setSenderDisplayName(fromaddress);
```

It is working fine, i am also getting admin address in that. So i have two mail address in 'from address'. The one i am setting in **setSenderDisplayName** and other default admin address.
How to override the admin one, i don't want admin address in 'from address'. How to achieve this?
And also every time **setSenderDisplayName** will be different so that i cannot use **setOrgWideEmailAddressId**. Any workaround for this?

Comment: If you want to set it, you need to use the `Organization-Wide Email Address` feature. It is hard to tell why you think it won't work here. Can you please **[edit]** your post to clarify?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Because I have to set different mail ids every time in setSenderDisplayName. We cannot use setSenderDisplayName  and setOrgWideEmailAddressId both at a time.